# query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql

i have table like below   with name student

```
     S.No    Name 
      1.    Ramesh
      2.    Raju
      3.    SOmu
    -------------
    -------------  etc
```

My requirement is when i am passing the S.no i  will get the Name by using function

My function like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(v_sno bigint)
  RETURNS TEXT
  AS
$BODY$

    DECLARE RESULT  VARCHAR(5000);

    BEGIN   
        SELECT  RESULT  "Name"  FROM "Student" WHERE "s.no" = v_sno;

        RETURN RESULT;
     END;

 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION fn_name(bigint)
  OWNER TO postgresql
```

but i  am getting the following error .

> ERROR: query has no destination for result data
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function fn_name(bigint) line 6 at SQL statement

please help me how to resolve the above issue.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: Hello I've never seen the object in which you wish to store the data shoe horned into a sql statement like that. (SELECT  RESULT  "Name")

Comment: What's wrong with manual? Just copy/paste one of the examples, change it a little bit and you're done.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(v_sno bigint)
  RETURNS TEXT
  AS
$BODY$

    DECLARE RESULT  VARCHAR(5000);

    BEGIN   
        SELECT  "Name"  into RESULT   FROM "Student" WHERE "s.no" = v_sno;

        RETURN RESULT;
     END;

 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION fn_name(bigint)
  OWNER TO postgresql

Answer (score 3):

The immediate question is [easily answered by the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) (see `SELECT INTO`).

However, all that is a rather overcomplicated way to do what you want. Things notably wrong:

- `varchar(5000)` is weird and unnecessary. Use `text` or unqualified `varchar`.
- `SELECT  RESULT  "Name"` doesn't do what you probably think it does. That's trying to `SELECT` a column named `result` and alias it as `Name`. I think you were looking for `SELECT INTO`.
- `"s.no"` means the column named `s.no`. Is that what you meant? Because that's a horrid name for a column; without the quotes it'd be interpreted as the column `no` from the table `s`. Don't use periods in column names or table names.

All you really need is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(bigint)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
SELECT "Name" FROM "Student" WHERE "s.no" = $1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

(assuming `"s.no"` really is your column name, not a mangled attempt at an alias).

If you had to use PL/PgSQL for this simple job for some reason (maybe you intend to make it more complex later), you'd write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(v_sno bigint)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    result text;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO result "Name" FROM "Student" WHERE "s.no" = $1;
    RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: ALTER FUNCTION fn_name   OWNER TO postgresql