# How do you use SELECT...FOR UPDATE in a function?

Tags: postgresql, locking, psql

Going off of [this example](http://shiroyasha.io/selecting-for-share-and-update-in-postgresql.html), I am trying to lock someone's credit card account (row), check to see if they have enough money, and if they do, use it to pay. I need to lock it to prevent a condition where they have enough credit, but then it is used on another transaction and my program is left thinking it still does have enough credits.

At the terminal level I can accomplish this like so: I can open two `psql` sessions in two terminals and I can issue a `SELECT * FROM credit_card WHERE credit_card_number = 1234 FOR UPDATE;` command in one and then a `SELECT * FROM credit_card FOR UDPATE` in the other (or something else like `UPDATE credit_card SET credits = credits -99 WHERE credit_card_number = 1234`), and I can see that the former call blocks the latter call. However, when I do the same thing but in a function like so

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (p_credit_card_number BIGINT)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM credit_card WHERE credit_card_number = p_credit_card_number FOR UPDATE
    ...
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I get the typical `query has no destination for result data` error (eg. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671574/query-has-no-destination-for-result-data)).

**Question:** How can I lock a specific row, or number of rows, while using `SELECT ...FOR UPDATE` inside a Function while avoiding the above mentioned error?? If not possible, or not advisable, how else would I do this inside a Function?

Comment: Use `PERORM`. See [Perform](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, `PERFORM * FROM credit_card WHERE credit_card_number = p_credit_card_number FOR UPDATE`?

Comment: Yes per the docs in the link I sent: "Write the query the same way you would write an SQL SELECT command, but replace the initial keyword SELECT with PERFORM."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting has nothing to do whit the "for update" clause. It works exactly the same in a stored procedure of not. The error you has to to do this a select statement inside a procedure (or function or do block). When you select in a procedure you **must** tell the procedure what to do with the selected variable(s).
This you do with the Select <column_list> into <variable_list> ...  
So assuming you actually need the data then something like the following:

```
create or replace function foo (p_credit_card_number bigint)
  returns void
  language 'plpgsql'
as $$
    v_credit_card  credit_card%type;
begin
    select * 
      into v_credit_card
      from credit_card 
      where credit_card_number = p_credit_card_number 
        for update;
    ...
    
    update credit_card
      set ... 
    where credit_card =  v_credit_card ;
      
end;
$$;
```

A more common usage though is to create a cursor and update using 'where current of'

```
create or replace function foo (p_credit_card_number bigint)
  returns void
  language 'plpgsql'
as $$
    c_credit_cards cursor for 
        select * 
          from credit_card 
         where credit_card_number = p_credit_card_number 
           for update;
    v_credit_card  credit_card%type;
begin

    for v_cc in c_credit_cards 
    loop
       ... additional processing ... 
    
       update credit_card
          set ... 
        where current of c_credit_cards;
    end loop; 
   ... 
end;
```

But note that when the cursor is opened ALL rows in it are locked.

Comment: I will accept this, but I'd like to point out that `PERFORM * FROM credit_card WHERE credit_card_number = p_credit_card_number FOR UPDATE` works just as well